# Why doesn't my ng-model update with Typeahead in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, typeahead.js, angular-ngmodel

In a website I'm building with [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) I've got an input with a typeahead below for which I use [angular-typeahead](https://github.com/Siyfion/angular-typeahead). It works fine in Chrome, Opera and Safari but not in Firefox. The problem seems to be that in Firefox the model isn't updating when I click the typeahead suggestion.

My html looks like this:

```
<input class="typeahead" sf-typeahead type="text" datasets="userDataset" ng-model="searchUser" >
<button ng-click="sendToUser(searchUser.id)" class="btn">Send</button>
```

and in my controller I have this simple function:

```
$scope.sendToUser = function(userId){
    console.log(userId);
    // More code here..
}
```

In Chrome, Opera and Safari it logs an int for the `userId`, but in Firefox it just logs `undefined`.

I made a [plunker for it here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ke08lFsBBwR1SOSIn7h8?p=preview) to show what I mean (search for "one", or "two").

It works in Chrome, Opera and Safari, but in Firefox it somehow shows `undefined` in the console. The extra weird thing is that it only shows `undefined` the first time. If you select something a second time it does work.

Does anybody know why this doesn't work in Firefox, and most importantly, how I can solve it? All tips are welcome!

Comment: I tried your Plunker in Chrome and FF. Both seem to work well. There are times when the model can be "unselected" with a click outside the TypeAhead in FF. So the model is bound correctly, but then unbound. The moment I hit "Send" Button with selection made, that error does not re-appear until I make another selection.

Comment: @DaveAlperovich - Alright, so would you know how we could keep the model selected when using Firefox?

Comment: Not yet. Very odd behavior. The Model Parser is being fired, meaning, somehow, the click event kicks off a digest cycle (odd already), and uses current index for a value. Both are very bizarre. I cannot find a bound event that corresponds to this yet.

Comment: Yes, I see what is happening. The `ng-model` binding conflicts with the object assignment. Upon selection, you are setting your "searchUser" to value of an object. But, the moment afterward, that the digest cycle runs, "searchUser" becomes a string bound to input. This string has no child id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an interesting Dilemma.

- the **TypeAhead** sets the `ng-model` value to an object once selected
- Upon any event (like click) that runs the digest cycle, the framework enforces the `ng-model` binding,assigning the model value a string bound to the input.
- **FireFox**, unlike **Chrome** seems to enforce this behavior. **Chrome** inputs probably allow for object value setting (just a guess).

---

**The work around is to change your output binding:**

```
<input class="typeahead" sf-typeahead type="text"  datasets="userDataset" 
outputval="searchUser" ng-model="a" options="exampleOptions">
```

The `outputval` is our expected value. I bound to a random scope variable `a` because the directive expects and uses a model binding.

Inside the directive, I changed the `updateScope` function to set the selected value to `scope.outputval` and commented out the assignment to Model.

```
    function updateScope (object, suggestion, dataset) {
      scope.$apply(function () {
        var newViewValue = (angular.isDefined(scope.suggestionKey)) ?
            suggestion[scope.suggestionKey] : suggestion;
        console.log(newViewValue);    
        //ngModel.$setViewValue(newViewValue);
        scope.outputval = newViewValue;
      });
    }
```

Try my **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/72vyzCZtQGWaiX5tEYTY?p=preview)**!